# Anova when both nested and crossed factors are present - specifying error term in `aov` in `R`

Tags: r, anova, mixed-model, nested-data

I have some data as follows.

```
set.seed(123)

df <- data.frame(condition = rep(c(rep("high", 60), rep("low", 60)),2),
           class = rep(c(rep(1, 20), rep(2, 20), rep(3,20)), 4),
           genotype = rep(c(1:60, 1:60),2),
           replication = c(rep(1,120), rep(2,120)),
           y = rnorm(n = 240, mean = 83, sd = 85))
```

Condition and class are crossed factors

```
table(df$class,df$condition)
    high low
  1   40  40
  2   40  40
  3   40  40
```

Condition and genotype are crossed factors

```
table(df$condition,df$genotype)
       1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34
  high 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
  low  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2

       35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60
  high  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
  low   2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
```

Genotypes are nested within class

```
table(df$class,df$genotype)

    1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35
  1 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4
  3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0

    36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60
  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  2  4  4  4  4  4  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  3  0  0  0  0  0  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4
```

I am trying to follow [Nested anova example with the aov function](https://rcompanion.org/rcompanion/d_07.html)

How to specify the error term here, when both nested and crossed factors are present?

```
m1 <- aov(y ~ condition*class + Error(class/genotype), data=df)
m2 <- aov(y ~ condition*class + Error(genotype), data=df)
m3 <- aov(y ~ condition*class + Error(genotype/(condition*class), data=df)
```

I need to test null hypothesis
1) $ \mu_1 = \mu_2 = .......= \mu_{60} $ for genotypes

2) $ \mu_{high} = \mu_{low}  $ for condition

3) $ \mu_1 = \mu_2 = \mu_3 $ for class

and post hoc comparions
$ \mu_{high1} = \mu_{high2} $,

$ \mu_{high1} = \mu_{high3} $

$ \mu_{high2} = \mu_{high3} $

$ \mu_{low1} = \mu_{low2} $,

$ \mu_{low1} = \mu_{low2} $

$ \mu_{low2} = \mu_{low3} $

Which residual values to use for these?

**Edit**
The design is as follows.
[image]

Comment: Your data and analysis purposes are not clear (to me). What is `replication`?
 Can you describe your experimental design? In any case, if you want to test the effect of genotypes for equality, then it's a fixed factor, not a random one, it should be outside of the Error.

Comment: @amoeba I have added the design in the question. I would like to test the genotypes, class as well as condition for equality.

Comment: You might consider using the mixed effects model options discussed at the link you cite, using the lme4 or nlme packages. Reading a book on mixed effects models, such as the one by Pinheiro and Bates, may be helpful (https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2Fb98882).

Otherwise, a good textbook on analysis of experiments may be helpful in determining what the error term should be for each of the hypothesis tests you're interested in. I remember there being a procedure for this, but it's been many years since I looked at it.